# Turtle true freehand drawing

Tags: python, python-turtle

I want to start drawing with the mouse, and I had the idea to do onclick and then the turtle comes to the mouse, and then ondrag turtle I start the freehand drawing, although turtle doesn't detect the dragging. Here is the code. Can you help?

```python
import turtle


def go_to_mouse(x, y):
    my_pen.penup()
    my_pen.goto(x, y)
    my_pen.pendown()


def click_right(x, y):
    my_pen.clear()


def drag_handler(x, y):
    my_pen.ondrag(None)
    my_pen.goto(x, y)
    my_pen.ondrag(drag_handler)


window = turtle.Screen()
window.setup(width=1000, height=1000)
window.title('drawing')
window.delay(0)

my_pen = turtle.Turtle()
my_pen.speed(0)
my_pen.color("red")
my_pen.penup()
my_pen.goto(0, 0)
my_pen.pendown()

my_pen.ondrag(drag_handler)
window.onclick(go_to_mouse, 1)
turtle.onscreenclick(click_right, 3)
window.listen()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's first be clear that your code works if you "click again" after the turtle moves to your position.  The issue is you don't want to "click again", but rather continue to hold the screen click and start dragging.

The way I was able to figure out to do this was to *install* and `import` pyautogui to simulate the missing click:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from pyautogui import mouseDown

def go_to_mouse(x, y):
    screen.onclick(None, 1)  # disable until turtle.release()

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.onrelease(release_handler)

    screen.ontimer(mouseDown)

def click_right(x, y):
    turtle.clear()

def drag_handler(x, y):
    turtle.ondrag(None)
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.ondrag(drag_handler)

def release_handler(x, y):
    turtle.onrelease(None)
    screen.onclick(go_to_mouse, 1)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=1000, height=1000)
screen.title('drawing')

turtle = Turtle('turtle')
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.color('red')
turtle.ondrag(drag_handler)

screen.onclick(go_to_mouse, 1)
screen.onclick(click_right, 3)

screen.mainloop()
```

I'm using a larger cursor to make sure we don't missposition the "click again".  I can't test the right click functionality on my system.